# i m using 4 imageview in relativelayout and i want to make dynamically. u can see screenshot below

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

i m using 4 imageview  in relativelayout and that images size equal to each other in relative layout but want to make dynamically but i m not getting

---

### Heading

```
final ImageView profile_img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_img1);
    final ImageView profile_img2 = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_img2);

    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);
    int width = point.x;
    final double margin_15 = width * 0.15;

    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.relative_profile);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parms.setMargins((int) margin_15, 0, (int) margin_15, 0);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(parms);

 //   Toast.makeText(activity,width+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            width_relativelayout = relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
            h_relativelayout = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

            // Toast.makeText(activity,width_linearlayout+"===",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms_img = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( width_relativelayout/2,350);
            parms_img.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            profile_img1.setLayoutParams(parms_img);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms_img2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width_relativelayout/2,300);
            parms_img.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            profile_img1.setLayoutParams(parms_img2);
            profile_img2.setLayoutParams(parms_img2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why dont you use `gridView`, `gridLayout` ?

Comment: Might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802004/add-imageviews-dynamically-on-android

Comment: right side in relative layout  above i m using  one more relative layout inside textview  and i m set background shadow that why i m using relativelayout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add imageViews dynamically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802004/add-imageviews-dynamically-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RecyclerView` and Adapter for same.
and Set `GridLayoutManager` with number count to show, like 2 for two image view horizontally.

Or you can `ArrayList` of `ImageView`.